# Count duplicates and get unique properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that looks something like this

```
let myArray = [
  {
    id:"1", 
    tool:{
      type: 'first',
      categories: [
        {
          id:'4',
          name:'Car'
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  {
    id:"2", 
    tool:{
      type: 'second',
      categories: [
        {
          id:'4', 
          name:'Car'
        },
        {
          id:'5', 
          name:'Plane'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

I wish to pull out some data about the categories. The desired result is an object containing unique id's with name and the count of how many times the name was present.
Something like this:

```
let categories = {
    4: {
        name: 'Car',
        count: 2
    },
    5: {
        name: 'Plane',
        count: 1
    },
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
let result = {}

let unique = [...new Set(myArray.map((item) => {

  return [...new Set(item.tool.categories.map((item) => {


    result[item.id] = (result[item.id] || 0) + 1;


  }))];


}))];
```

which gives me

```
[object Object] {
  4: 2,
  5: 1
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/motulivudo/edit?js,console)

I'm not an experienced javascripter and it is very possible that these loops in loops are very ineffective so any suggestions are much appreciated.
I expect the array to have a max of 1000 object.

/ j

Question update:
What if I wish to change the output slightly to this:

```
let categories = [
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Car',
        count: 2
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Plane',
        count: 1
    },
]
```

this is what I have so far:

```
const count = myArray.reduce((count, obj) => {
  obj.tool.categories.forEach(({ id, name }) => {
    count[id] = count[id] || { count: 0, name, id };
    count[id].count++;
  });

  return count;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off site to review the main issue. While very helpful, demos are only to support what actually exists in the question

Comment: @charlietfl sure that was a mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use just the result set as object for counting.

```js
let myArray = [{ id: "1", tool: { type: 'first', categories: [{ id: '4', name: 'Car' }] } }, { id: "2", tool: { type: 'second', categories: [{ id: '4', name: 'Car' }, { id: '5', name: 'Plane' }] } }],
    categories = myArray.reduce((r, a) =>
        (a.tool.categories.forEach(b =>
            (r[b.id] = r[b.id] || { name: b.name, count: 0 }).count++), r), {});

console.log(categories);
```

Proposal for extended question.

```js
let myArray = [{ id: "1", tool: { type: 'first', categories: [{ id: '4', name: 'Car' }] } }, { id: "2", tool: { type: 'second', categories: [{ id: '4', name: 'Car' }, { id: '5', name: 'Plane' }] } }],
    categories = myArray.reduce((map =>
        (r, a) =>
            (a.tool.categories.forEach(b =>
                (!map.has(b.id) && map.set(b.id, r[r.push({ id: b.id, name: b.name, count: 0 }) - 1]), map.get(b.id).count++)), r))(new Map), []);

console.log(categories);
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your input. Seems like you all agree on the way to handle this.

Comment: Thank you once again. I want to be this smart in my next life :) Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate the object, and collect the categories into an object map:

```js
const myArray = [{
  id: "1",
  tool: {
    type: 'first',
    categories: [{
      id: '4',
      name: 'Car'
    }]
  }
}, {
  id: "2",
  tool: {
    type: 'second',
    categories: [{
      id: '4',
      name: 'Car'
    }, {
      id: '5',
      name: 'Plane'
    }]
  }
}];

const count = myArray.reduce((count, obj) => {
  obj.tool.categories.forEach(({ id, name }) => {
    count[id] = count[id] || { count: 0, name };
    count[id].count++;
  });

  return count;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the original array and return an object with the correct properties

```js
let myArray = [{
    id: "1",
    tool: {
        type: 'first',
        categories: [{
            id: '4',
            name: 'Car'
        }]
    }
}, {
    id: "2",
    tool: {
        type: 'second',
        categories: [{
            id: '4',
            name: 'Car'
        }, {
            id: '5',
            name: 'Plane'
        }]
    }
}];

let categories = myArray.reduce( (a,b) => {
    return b.tool.categories.forEach( (obj) => {
     obj.id in a ? a[obj.id].count++ : a[obj.id]={count : 1,name:obj.name};
    }), a;
},{});

console.log(categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```
    myArray.forEach(({tool:{categories}}) => categories
      .forEach(cat => cats[cat["id"]] = {
          [cat["name"]]:cat.name
          , count: (cats[cat["id"]] && ++cats[cat["id"]]["count"] || 1)
        }
      )
    );
```

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    id:"1", 
    tool:{
      type: 'first',
      categories: [
        {
          id:'4',
          name:'Car'
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  {
    id:"2", 
    tool:{
      type: 'second',
      categories: [
        {
          id:'4', 
          name:'Car'
        },
        {
          id:'5', 
          name:'Plane'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

let cats = {};
    myArray.forEach(({tool:{categories}}) => categories
      .forEach(cat => cats[cat["id"]] = {
          [cat["name"]]:cat.name
          , count: (cats[cat["id"]] && ++cats[cat["id"]]["count"] || 1)
        }
      )
    );

console.log(cats);
```